# Abstract logic from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Amateur ruby-ist here...

I have a set of rake tasks that look like:

```
namespace :download do
  task :only do
     config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]

     username = config['username'] 
     password = config['password'] ? "-p#{config['password']}" : nil
  end
  task :environment do
     config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]

     username = config['username'] 
     password = config['password'] ? "-p#{config['password']}" : nil
  end
end
```

How do I abstract the 'config' logic (inclusing the username and password) 
or define it globally?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

After your tasks add

```
def config
  ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]
end
```

But you can also do

```
def username
  config['username']
end

def password
  config['password'] ? "-p#{config['password']}" : nil
end
```

Comment: I guess I meant how to I abstract the config and the username and password, but thanks. I will edit the question

Comment: thanks! yes like that, however, is there a way to do this without defining each variable individually? I am potentially adding a handful more config variables, and it would seem a little lengthy to spread it out like that.

Comment: Your config method could return a hash: `{ username: ..., password:... }`

Comment: ok thanks. I  will give that a try. I will leave this question open and see if anyone has other ideas, but I'll mark it correct in a few hours. Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 0):

I think @b-seven answer is the best option for clarity, but you can use meta-programming something like:

```
namespace :download do
  task :only do
    # just use username or password
  end
  task :environment do
    # just use username or password
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
  define_method key do
    value
  end
end
```

BTW In my test I had to use `Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]`